# Want General Screen scraping application ( like facebook has ) for django

Tags: django, screen-scraping

The use case of what I want is -
The user enters the link url ( like you might be doing in your facebook stat update box )
And a short description of this url with its title and a thumbnail appear.
( Yeah, the basic process is "sharing a link" )

How would you go about doing it ?
Call a django app which scrapes urls ( if yes then which one ? )
Do it using javascript? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), a very potent DOM crawler. With it, you could scrape URL's for  tags and display them. The same goes for page titles.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a thumbnail have a look at [python-webkit2png](https://github.com/AdamN/python-webkit2png/).

Comment: isn't there one with lesser dependencies .